# How to create objects on runtime and move them?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to create objects on my game update and move them. This is my banana object:

```
function Banana() {
    this.height = 1.96;
    this.width = 3.955;
    this.pos_x = CENTER - this.width/2;
    this.pos_y = -475;
    this.banana_image = banana_image;
};
```

And this is the Move method:

```
Banana.prototype.move = function(){
    if (this.pos_y > 500) {
        //this.banana_image.parentElement.removeChild(this.banana_image);
    }
    this.height += ZOOM_RATE;
    this.width += ZOOM_RATE;
    this.pos_y += 3;
    this.pos_x -= SIDES_RATE;
};
```

This is the Game Update part:

```
Game.update = function() {

      this.player.move();

      //creating bananas
      if (objs.lenght <= 0) {
          this.banana = new Banana();
      } else {
          for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
              objs.push(new Banana());
          }  
      }

      //moving bananas
      for (i = 0; i < objs.lenght; i++) {
          this.objs[0].move();
      }


};
```

Game Draw:

```
function Game.draw = function() { 
    this.context.drawImage(road, 0,0, rw, rh); 
    this.context.drawImage(
        this.player.player_image, 
        this.player.pos_x, this.player.pos_y, 
        this.player.width, this.player.height); 
    this.context.drawImage(
        this.banana.banana_image, 
        this.banana.pos_x, this.banana.pos_y, 
        this.banana.width, this.banana.height); 
};
```

I tried to ask this to multiple people, but I can't find an answer for it.

Comment: You have a typos in `update` -- should be `length`. Where's your animation loop?

Comment: I have a Draw function

`Game.draw = function() {
 
  this.context.drawImage(road, 0,0, rw, rh);
  
  this.context.drawImage(this.player.player_image,
         this.player.pos_x, 
         this.player.pos_y, 
         this.player.width, 
         this.player.height);
  
  this.context.drawImage(this.banana.banana_image,
         this.banana.pos_x,
         this.banana.pos_y,
         this.banana.width,
         this.banana.height);

};`

Comment: You must have an animation loop to "move" your game items. Here is some [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/1892/introduction-to-html5-canvas/11659/detecting-mouse-position-on-the-canvas) showing how to use an animation loop.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to move the objects 10 times and then stop.

First you need to add a line to the start of `Game.draw`, so that it clears the canvas making you always start drawing from scratch:

```
this.context.clearRect(0,0,500,500); // clear canvas, adjust box size if needed
```

Then make a function to call both `update` and `draw`, and queue that function to be called again:

```
var count = 10;

function updateAndDraw() {
    Game.update();
    Game.draw();
    count--;
    if (count) requestAnimationFrame(updateAndDraw);
}

// start moving:
requestAnimationFrame(updateAndDraw);
```

The movement may go too fast to your liking, so then adjust the `move` method to make smaller changes, or use `setTimeout` instead of `requestAnimationFrame` (but that will make the animation less fluent).

Note that you have a few errors in your code, which you will need to fix first:

- `lenght` should be `length`
- `function Game.draw = function() {`: remove `function` before `Game.draw`.
- ... check the error messages you get in console.